Original error: Cannot verify the signature . Original error: The 'java.exe' binary could not be found neither in PATH n
I've already set path JAVA_HOME AND ANDROID_HOME still getting issue
I update my android studio sdk tool version
Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\pushkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium Server GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-s

